# Control Xbox One remotely over the network without developer tools/account

Tags: linux, command-line, xbox-one

I have a Retropie plugged into the Xbox's auxillary/passthru HDMI port. This is fairly convenient, but does require the Xbox to be turned on and to be running whatever they call that app (the one with the three lines as an icon).

I'd like to have a short script of some sort that could run on the Retropie whenever it wakes up. The script would check to see if the Xbox is powered on (unsure how to accomplish that), and if it wasn't it would send a power-on command (there are several github projects that do as much), and I feel competent to install one of those and get it working.

After that is accomplished, I'd like the script to automatically start the relevant app.

I also know this is possible over the network (in theory) because the iPhone app allows you to issue commands (like a remote, you have to arrow to the correct app, start it... not as simple as running one directly or by id).

Is there any open source (or otherwise free) software that can send such commands to the Xbox? Even if I sniff the packets being sent by the iPhone, there's likely some security stuff that will make it more complicated than simply playing back those packets' contents.

I've searched Google and github, but either there's nothing to find (or just as likely) I can't think of the correct keywords to pull up something relevant. The few software products that seem to do this sort of thing are all intended for Xbox game development, making them less useful (or not at all) for my intended purpose.

Comment: Could someone explain to me why this is being voted closed? It's a genuine question, it's within the purview of this SE, it hasn't been asked before, and I'm clear on what it is I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xbox One relies on a particular remote control protocol called "Smartglass". Several different open source software packages use this to integrate with the Xbox for remote control purposes such as Home Assistant. (in addition to the non-open source ones like the iPhone Xbox app).

There is a [Python module](https://pypi.org/project/xbox-smartglass-core/) for this protocol, which will allow you to write scripts that can control the Xbox.